# How to use Depth of Field in CIFilter?

Tags: ios, objective-c, image-processing, cifilter

I am trying to implement **Depth of Field** in `CIFilter`
In the Core Image Filter Reference of Apple Developer, it says about `inputPoint0` and `inputPoint1`

> The focused region of the image stretches in a line between `inputPoint0` and `inputPoint1` of the Image.

So I Changed the UI kit coordinate system to Core Image coordinate system and set these points. But the output always appears in **all Blurred image** or **all Focused image**. there is no depth.

Can somebody give me a snippet code to implement **CIFilter Depth of Field**?

and give me some explain about that code? **especially related to `inputPoint`**

Below is the code what I am working on.

**Depth of Field Method**

```
@implementation CIImage (myCustomExtension)    
+(CIImage *) CIFilterDepthOfField:(CIImage *)inputImage inputPoint0:(CIVector *) inputPoint0 inputPoint1:(CIVector *) inputPoint1 inputSaturation:(CGFloat) inputSaturation inputUnsharpMaskRadius:(CGFloat)inputUnsharpMaskRadius inputUnsharpMaskIntensity:(CGFloat) inputUnsharpMaskIntensity inputRadius:(CGFloat) inputRadius{
    CIFilter *depthOfField = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIDepthOfField" withInputParameters:@{kCIInputImageKey:inputImage, @"inputPoint0":inputPoint0, @"inputPoint1":inputPoint1, kCIInputSaturationKey:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:inputSaturation], @"inputUnsharpMaskRadius":[NSNumber numberWithFloat:inputUnsharpMaskRadius], @"inputUnsharpMaskIntensity":[NSNumber numberWithFloat:inputUnsharpMaskIntensity], kCIInputRadiusKey:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:inputRadius]}];

    return [depthOfField outputImage];
}
@end
```

**My implementation in custom class**

```
//Depth Of Field
CIVector *point0 = [CIVector vectorWithX:self.point.x Y:self.point.y];
CIVector *point1 = [CIVector vectorWithX:self.point.x Y:self.point.y+ 300];
outputCIImage = [CIImage CIFilterDepthOfField:outputCIImage inputPoint0:point0 inputPoint1:point1 inputSaturation:1.5 inputUnsharpMaskRadius:0.5 inputUnsharpMaskIntensity:2.5 inputRadius:6];
UIImage *outputUIImage = [UIImage renderCIImageToUIImage:outputCIImage withCIContext:self.ciContext];

self.imageView.image = outputUIImage;
```

**Point is from tap recognizer**

```
- (IBAction)touchPointSet:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    //Get point in imageview
    CGPoint point = [sender locationInView:self.imageView];
    //Calculate image scale for image view image
    CGFloat imageScale = fminf(self.imageView.frame.size.width/self.imageView.image.size.width, self.imageView.frame.size.height/self.imageView.image.size.height);
    //Calculate point in image bound
    CGPoint pointInImage = CGPointMake(point.x - ((self.imageView.frame.size.width - self.imageView.image.size.width * imageScale) / 2), point.y - ((self.imageView.frame.size.height - self.imageView.image.size.height * imageScale) / 2));

    //Make transform
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, -1);
    transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, 0, -self.imageView.image.size.height * imageScale);

    //Transform point to Core image coordinate
    CGPoint transformedPoint = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(pointInImage, transform);

    CGFloat screenScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
    self.point = CGPointMake(transformedPoint.x * screenScale, transformedPoint.y * screenScale);
}
```

**This is rendering method CIImage To UIImage**

```
@implementation UIImage (myCustomExtension)
+(UIImage *) renderCIImageToUIImage:(CIImage *) CIImage withCIContext:(CIContext *) CIContext{
    CGImageRef CGImageFromCIImage = [CIContext createCGImage:CIImage fromRect:CIImage.extent];
    UIImage *UIImageFromCGImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:CGImageFromCIImage];
    CGImageRelease(CGImageFromCIImage);

    return UIImageFromCGImage;
}
@end
```

Comment: I am about to go offline for 6-7 hours, sorry, but can you post the code you are currently using? It sounds like you understand how to implement CI filters (and you described the issue very well) but without this code it's tough to help.

Comment: @dfd I added my code. Thank you for trying to help!

Comment: As a book writer I say that Apple should refrain from writing documentation. All their docs are appalling from the didactics point of view. It looks like they hate creating documentations by the way they throw half-cooked texts polluting the web with garbage. By the way, it is cleat that they hate developers too. You waste hours just to understand how their APIs work. Don't take me wrong, I love Apple products but everything they do for developers are crap.

Comment: I have the same issue, do you remember if you managed to find a solution ?